# How to scan or parse e-tickets to extract information from it in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to scan or parse Flight E-Tickets, to extract information like confirmation number, flight number, Airline name, Trip Start date and end date. At first i am reading mails from my email where i can find my E-Tickets using IMAP like,

```
using (Imap imap = new Imap())
{
    imap.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
    imap.Login("***@gmail.com", "XXXX");
    imap.SelectInbox();
    List<long> uids = imap.Search(Flag.All);
    foreach (long uid in uids)
    {
       string eml = imap.GetMessageByUID(uid);
       IMail email = new MailBuilder().CreateFromEml(eml);
       ....
       ....
    }
}
```

Here actually my difficult part arises, There are plenty of airlines are out, each follow their own design or specification for E-Ticket appearance and they might re-newal their E-ticket every 3 months or they can have individual style for every flight's ticket. so it is not good standard, to write conditions like,

```
If AmericanAirlines:
....do stuff for AA....
Else If SouthAirlines:
....do stuff for AA....
..
..
```

At first i taught to use HtmlAgilityPack to parse e-tickets, since all are designed or prepared using Html, so i can use this library to parse DOM Elements and extract the information from it. But it will become very complex, I need to write parsing code for air lines ticket. so i have decided to use Regular Expressions to match Confirmation number and airline name like,

```
 string code = "";
 Match match = Regex.Match(email.Text.Replace("*", ""), @"\s*((Record\s*Locator)|(Confirmation\s*[a-zA-Z]{0,4})|(AIR\s*Confirmation)|(Flight\s*Confirmation))(\s*)(\#*)(\s*)(\:*)(\s*)[A-Z0-9]{6}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 if (match.Success)
 {
     string s = Regex.Replace(match.Value, @"\\r\\n", "").Trim();
     code = s.Substring(s.Length - 6);
     if (!confirmcodes.Any(m => m == code))
        confirmcodes.Add(code);
  }
  string airline = "";
  Match airlinematch = Regex.Match(email.Text.Replace("*", ""), @"\s*(.*)\s*((Air\s*lines\s*)|(Air\s*ways\s*))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  if (airlinematch.Success)
  {
      string s = Regex.Replace(airlinematch.Value, @"\\r\\n", "").Trim();
      airline = airlinematch.Groups[0].Value;
  }
```

The above condition might satisfied for only certain airlines, if the ticket is designed in very unusual way, condition will break. so please guide me the better strategy to scan flight e-tickets that fit for any type of Airline's ticket. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion you would want the conditions to break if there is any variation in the eticket design. As it would indicate that the layout of the eticket has changed and who knows what kind of invalid information you would be getting: a flight number is suddenly a seat number, a airline name is suddenly the passenger name etc. I would recommend using the html agility pack to parse the emails, regex just isn't suited to parse nest based structures. But you are just going to have to face the music. They will change the layout of their tickets and you'll need to update you conditions every time.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a more flexible two steps system:

#### Step 1: Find and extract the whole information

I would use a parser for locating the information. I'd ask the parser to extract this information as text.

```
HtmlParser parser = new HtmlParser();
parser.loadHtml(...);

String information = parser.select('div#information').toString();
```

#### Step2: Analyze the extracted information

With the help of an XML file, I would put in it the various regexes used for extracting the desired information.

My file would look like this:

```
<regexes>
    <regex name="AA Airlines">
        <name><![CDATA[AA\s+\w+]]></name>
        <seat><![CDATA[\d+]]></seat>
        ...
    </regex>

    <regex name="South Airlines">
        <name><![CDATA[South\s*[a-z]]]></name>
        <seat><![CDATA[\d{2}-\d{4}-\d+]]></seat>
        ...
    </regex>

    ...
</regexes>
```

Then in my C# code, I would parse the above small config file and check my `information` against each "variant". Later, if new variant appears, I would simply update my small config file.